# Spatial Index issues using orientdb-enterprise-2.2.21 and orientdb-community-2.2.21

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am attempting to create a spatial index via the Java API I am using Orient DB orientdb-enterprise-2.2.21. *Running the tests using a Remote connection.* I have attempted to create using several approaches Class and properties have been created.

```
        nodeClass = graph.createVertexType(NODE_CLASS_NAME);
        nodeClass.createProperty("latitude", OType.DOUBLE);
        nodeClass.createProperty("longitude", OType.DOUBLE);
        nodeClass.createProperty("name", OType.STRING);
        nodeClass.createProperty("color", OType.STRING);
        nodeClass.createProperty("location", OType.EMBEDDED);
```

and the results are:

I am creating a spatial index in several ways and they all fail:

Case 1 the "old way":

```
nodeClass.createIndex("Group.latitude_longitude", "SPATIAL", null, null, "LUCENE", new String[] { "latitude", "longitude" });
```

Results:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexException: Index with type SPATIAL and algorithm null does not exist.
    DB name="demodb"
```

Case 2 :

```
     graph.command(new OCommandSQL(
        "CREATE INDEX Group.location ON Group(location) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE")).execute();
```

Results:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexException: Index with type SPATIAL and algorithm null does not exist.
    DB name="demodb"
```

Case 3 :

```
     OIndex<?> idx = nodeClass.getProperty("location").
              createIndex(OClass.INDEX_TYPE.SPATIAL, new ODocument().field("ignoreNullValues", true));
```

Results:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexException: Index with type SPATIAL and algorithm null does not exist.
    DB name="demodb"
```

pom:

```
<orientdb.version>2.2.21</orientdb.version>
<tinkerpop.version>2.6.0</tinkerpop.version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
        <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-lucene</artifactId>
        <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tinkerpop.gremlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-groovy</artifactId>
        <version>${tinkerpop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tinkerpop.gremlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin</artifactId>
        <version>${tinkerpop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Encountered the same behavior with orientdb-community-2.2.21.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the spatial plugin on the server?

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Spatial-Index.html

Comment: Thanks for feedback that did help. However, I had to create the property and the index using embedded SQL for it to work.  This was the only way it worked:               OCommandRequest commandRequest =
                graph.command(new OCommandSQL("CREATE INDEX Group.location ON Group(location) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE"));

Comment: To be clear I first needed -> (1)  graph.command(new OCommandSQL("CREATE PROPERTY Group.location EMBEDDED OPoint")).execute();         Then -> (2)  OCommandRequest commandRequest = graph.command(new OCommandSQL("CREATE INDEX Group.location ON Group(location) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE"));     Just seems a little  awkward to have to do this from Java.  Appreciate the info.